# I need to receive an java array with arrays inside it and make a report in a table

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to make a dataset run on a parameter field that is a collection that i receive from Java code.

I am trying

```xml
<datasetRun subDataset="EstruturaOrganicaDTO" uuid="c3ec8434-efe9-4dbe-8c1a-4ba8be684bda">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($P{EstruturasOrganicas}.getFieldValue( $F{estruturaOrganica}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

This is my report it just says he cant find field

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="objetivo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6cbf12c5-03fc-4c49-ac33-e581f0aa391f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="EstruturaOrganica" uuid="37e37553-5bbd-4474-aa35-1138420f9b25">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="codDivisao" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nomeDivisao" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="siglaDivisao" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="missao" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="visao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="EstruturaOrganicaDTO" uuid="8cc2ff0b-66f4-4417-bd17-d8d1ed73473a">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="estruturaOrganica" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="daf8a3e2-f448-4dbe-88ff-e1095ed9337e">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="EstruturasOrganicas" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="284" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="100" y="47" width="200" height="200" uuid="78b36e22-df70-4de8-87db-5011ead4bc8a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="EstruturaOrganicaDTO" uuid="c3ec8434-efe9-4dbe-8c1a-4ba8be684bda">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($P{EstruturasOrganicas}.getFieldValue( $F{estruturaOrganica}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="5dcf02b8-6426-497a-8624-d08f06632a5a">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I want to iterate in the field of parameter.

I'm doing this in Java

```java
List <EstruturaOrganicaDTO> constatacoes1 = new ArrayList<>();
EstruturaOrganicaDTO estruturaOrganicaDTO = new EstruturaOrganicaDTO();
estruturaOrganicaDTO
        .setEstruturaOrganica(
                new ArrayList<EstruturaOrganicaEntity>( ));
estruturaOrganicaDTO.getEstruturaOrganica().add(new EstruturaOrganicaEntity("abc", "123",
        "fdh", "123", "2456", false));

JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(constatacoes1);
final String jasperReportPath = "jasper-templates/objetivo.jrxml";

InputStream inputStreamTemplate = this.environment.resourceAsStream(jasperReportPath);

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamTemplate);

Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("EstruturasOrganicas", beanCollectionDataSource1);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());
File pdf = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf");
pdf.deleteOnExit();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
```

Comment: please share the error

Comment: Solved it by mapping the parameters in each subdataset